# How to build a compartmentalized heatmap

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization

Using D3, I want to take the data visualization type of a classical heatmap...

[image]

.. onto a compartmentalized version of several heatmap groups drawing data from a single data source.

[image]

Technically this should be one heatmap element drawing its data from a single source - separation and thus clustering/grouping is supposed to happen through sorting the data in the *.csv file (group one, group two, group three..) and the D3 *.JS file handling the styling.

While generating a single map:

```
    // Build X scales and axis:
    const x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(myGroups)
    .padding(0.00);
    svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Build Y scales and axis:
    const y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain(myVars)
    .padding(0.00);
    svg.append('g')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

assigning a color:

```
      // Assign color scale
    const myColor = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range(['red', '#750606'])
    .domain([1, 100]);
```

and fetching (sample) data:

```
// Read the data
d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/heatmap_data.csv', (data) => {
  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return myVars.indexOf(b.variable) - myVars.indexOf(a.variable) || myGroups.indexOf(a.group) - myGroups.indexOf(b.group)
  });
```

Has been working like a charm:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/ChrisBean/pen/ZEGjgEa)

**I'm struggling to expand this basic structure onto the generation of multiple groups as described above.** Expanding the color scheme, trying to build several additional X and Y axis that cover different ranges result in a complete break of the D3 element *rendering the map unable to be displayed at all.*

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to generate multiple heatmap groups without breaking the heatmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the compartmentalization using a row and column based procedure to construct the compartments:

```
    // Dimensions
  const numCategoryCols = 4;
  const numCategoryRows = Math.ceil(grouped.length / numCategoryCols);
  const numEntryCols = 3;
  const numEntryRows = Math.ceil(grouped[0].values.length / numEntryCols);
  const gridSize = 20;
  const width = gridSize * numCategoryCols * numEntryCols;
  const height = gridSize * numCategoryRows * numEntryRows;
  const tooltipArrowSize = 8;

  // Containers
  const container = d3
    .select("#" + containerId)
    .classed("heatmap-grid", true)
    .style("position", "relative");
  const svg = container
    .append("svg")
    .style("display", "block")
    .style("width", "100%")
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
    .style("opacity", 0); 

    svg.transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .delay((d,i) => i*200)
    .style("opacity", 1)

  // Heatmap
  const gCategory = svg
    .selectAll(".category-g")
    .data(grouped, (d) => d.key)
    .join("g")
    .attr("class", "category-g")
    .attr("fill", (d) => color(d.key))
    .attr("transform", (_, i) => {
      const y = Math.floor(i / numCategoryCols);
      const x = i % numCategoryCols;
      return `translate(${gridSize * numEntryCols * x},${
        gridSize * numEntryRows * y
      })`;
    });
  const gEntry = gCategory
    .selectAll(".entry-g")
    .data((d) => d.values)
    .join("g")
    .attr("class", "entry-g")
    .attr("transform", (_, i) => {
      const y = Math.floor(i / numEntryCols);
      const x = i % numEntryCols;
      return `translate(${gridSize * x},${gridSize * y})`;
    });
  const entry = gEntry
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", gridSize)
    .attr("height", gridSize)
    .attr("fill-opacity", (d) => d.Severity / 100)
    .on("mouseenter", showTooltip)
    .on("mouseleave", hideTooltip);
```